# nginx - 403 Forbidden error

Tags: nginx

I am trying to setup nginx and I am getting a 403 error. Below is how I have configured nginx under Centos7. FIrewall is not running.

> vi /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
            listen 80;
            server_name _;
            location / {
                    root /data/www;
                    index index.html;
       }
    }
```

The permissions are as follows:

```
namei -l /data/www/index.html 
f: /data/www/index.html
drwxr-xr-x root  root  /
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx data
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx www
-rwxr-xr-x nginx nginx index.html
```

The /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file says the user nginx is running under should be nginx. I checked and indeed the process is running under the nginx user.

Why am I still getting the 403 message?

Comment: Check SELinux policies.

Comment: Disabled and same issue.
I think I am about to give up on Centos7 and revert back to Centos 6.5

Comment: What's the error log content ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on CentOS 7, and I did what you did.

I solved it by setting globally SELinux to permissive mode.

`# setenforce 0`

You commented that you disabled SELinux, maybe you can check the logs to find out if it's really disabled

`sudo cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep -i nginx`

I've found my solution here: 
[NGINX: SELinux Changes...](http://nginx.com/blog/nginx-se-linux-changes-upgrading-rhel-6-6/)